# jquery dotdotdot plugin is not woriking for dynamically created html

Tags: jquery, dotdotdot, jquery-dotdotdot

I am creating elements using:

```
$('#articleview').append(articles);
```

I need to apply the dotdotdot plugin to this dynamically created html

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".ellipsis").dotdotdot();
});
```

but it's not working in dynamically created html

Comment: You will need to recall `$(".ellipsis").dotdotdot();` on dynamically added html.

Answer (score 1):

After the `$('#articleview').append(articles);`

call -

`$(".ellipsis").dotdotdot();`

And this should work...

`dotdotdot()` did it's work for first time the document was loaded. When you changed the content, it needed to be called again.

Comment: dotdotdot() did it's work for first time the document was loaded. When you changed the content, it needed to be called again.

Answer (score 0):

Always call plugins after dom ready other wise plugin unable to find markup and fail.

```js
var articles='Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text';
$('#wrapper').append(articles);
$(".ellipsis").dotdotdot();
```

```css
#wrapper {
    width: 100px;
    height: 20px;
  
}
```

```html
  
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://dotdotdot.frebsite.nl/js/jquery.dotdotdot-1.2.1.js"></script>
<div id="wrapper" class='ellipsis'></div>
```